# Showing that $ϕ(x)=x^n$ is a homomorphism from $G\to Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, transfer-theory

Let $G$ be a group with $|G:Z(G)|=n$ then $\phi(x)=x^n$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $Z(G)$.

I guess it has a proof using [transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_%28group_theory%29) theory, I wonder whether it has an elemantary proof or not. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, $x \mapsto x^n$ is exactly the transfer homomorphism from $G$ to $Z(G)$. I am not sure what you mean by elementary. The transfer homomorphism is not exactly rocket science! Since $[G,G]$ is in the kernel of $\phi$, it follows that $[G,G]$ has exponent at most $n$, and since $[G,G]$ is finitely generated, it follows that it is finite.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Almost everything is elemantary for you, Derek.

Comment: Not exactly. I can understand why you would look a for a proof of a purely group-theoretical result that avoids the use of character theory, because that involves techniques external to group theory, like theory of algebraic integers, but transfer theory is just pure group theory anyway.

Comment: @DerekHolt: What I mean we have $x^ny^n=(xy)^n$, and Is it it really necassary to define new concept or function to prove this ?
Can't we show this by using properties of $Z(G)$, or usual elementwise operation in a group ? Of course, the answer maybe no.

Comment: I would certainly be interested if you could, but my guess is that setting up the transfer homomorphism is the most natural and direct route to proving it. The problem is that if you try and do anything directly with $(xy)^n$ then you just a mess of commutators.

Comment: @mesel, "almost everthing is elementary for you" -  you could have been politer to Derek! He is a respected group theoretician!

Comment: @NickyHekster: This sencetence is actually showing my respect to him, Nicky. I was serious about that.

Comment: Can you please pick a more descriptive title?

Comment: @Aryabhata: if you could suggest one , I will.

Comment: "Showing that $\phi(x) = x^n$ is a homomorphism from $G \to Z(G)$.

Answer (score 5):

> Let $G$ be a group such that $Z(G)$ is of finite index $n$ in $G$. Then, the map $G \to G$, $g \mapsto g^n$ is a homomorphism.

*Direct proof.* Choose a system of representatives $R \subseteq G$ of $G/Z(G)$, $n=|R|$. The natural $G$-action on $G/Z(G)$ induces a $G$-action $e : G \times R \to R$ such that $gr Z(G) = e(g,r) Z(G)$, i.e. $e(g,r)^{-1} gr \in Z(G)$. It suffices to prove that
$$  \prod_{r \in R} (e(g,r)^{-1} gr) = g^n. ~~~ (\star)$$
In fact, for $g,h \in G$ this implies
$$(gh)^n \stackrel{(\star)}{=} \prod_{r \in R} e(gh,r)^{-1} ghr = \prod_{r \in R} e(g,e(h,r))^{-1} ghr = \prod_{r \in R} e(g,e(h,r))^{-1} g e(h,r) \cdot e(h,r)^{-1} hr\\ = \prod_{r \in R} e(g,e(h,r))^{-1} g e(h,r) \cdot \prod_{r \in R} e(h,r)^{-1} hr = \prod_{s \in R} e(g,s)^{-1} g s \cdot \prod_{r \in R} e(h,r)^{-1} hr\stackrel{(\star),(\star)}{=} g^n h^n.$$
To prove $(\star)$, we decompose the permutation $e(g,-) : R \to R$ into cycles. If $(r_1 \cdots r_k)$ is a cycle, i.e. $e(g,r_i)=r_{i+1}$ for $i<k$ and $e(g,r_k)=r_1$, we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^{k} (e(g,r_i)^{-1} g r_i) = (e(g,r_k)^{-1} g r_k) \dotsc (e(g,r_2)^{-1} g r_2) (e(g,r_1)^{-1} g r_1) = r_1^{-1} g^k r_1$$
Since this lies in $Z(G)$, we also have $g^k \in Z(G)$. But then $r_1^{-1} g^k r_1 = g^k$. Since $\prod_{r \in R} (e(g,r)^{-1} gr)$ is the product of all these products, indexed by the cycles, and the cycle lengths add up to $n$, we get $g^n$. $\square$

Notice that this is basically the usual proof which uses the transfer map, but we only have to construct it in the special case and don't need to show that it's independent from the system of representatives.

Comment: I don't get the "$(\star),(\star)$" step; care to add a few more details? -- Also, I suspect you can replace $Z(G)$ by any subgroup of $Z(G)$?

Comment: Since $e(g,r)^{-1} g r$ is central, the "big" product expands to two products, one being $g^n$ because of $(\star)$ and a variable substitution $r \leftrightarrow e(h,r)$, and the other being $h^n$ because of $(\star)$.

Comment: Your guess is right, subgroups of $Z(G)$ won't give anything more general. If $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$ of index $m$, then $n$ divides $m$ and hence the map $g \mapsto g^m$ is the map $g \mapsto g^n$ composed $m/n$-times with itsself.

Comment: Ouch! There are a few steps omitted here. Thanks for clarifying, but it wouldn't hurt to do so in the post itself.

Comment: Sorry, I was so immersed into the problem when I wrote up the solution that I thought that this step is trivial. I hope that you like my edit.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the kind of thing that is trivial when you know where the solution comes from, but since the point of your post was precisely to free the reader from having to know about transfer and group cohomology, it's a welcome improvement.