# Easier version of Burnside's transfer theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $pm$ with $p$ a prime that does not divide $m$. Suppose there exists a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P\leq G$ contained in the center of the group $Z$. Prove that there is a normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq G$ that satisfies $G = PN$ and $P\cap N = \langle e\rangle$ (in other words, $G$ is the internal direct product of $P$ and $N$).

I know this is a special case of Burnside's transfer theorem, but I am searching for an elementary proof which only uses the tools proved in a first course on group theory.

Comment: It is elementary to see that such $N$ exists if and only if $x \mapsto x^m$ is a homomorphism. Then see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842500/showing-that-%cf%95x-xn-is-a-homomorphism-from-g-to-zg). I think there is no proof known that isn't essentially proving that the transfer map is a homomorphism.

Comment: But anyway, the facts that you need about transfer for this result *can* be proven using tools from a first course in group theory. After all it just comes down to some manipulations with cosets and coset representatives. It is also simpler in this case, since $P$ is abelian. (In general transfer is a homomorphism $G \rightarrow H/[H,H]$ defined for any subgroup $H$.) Isaac's group theory book has a good exposition about transfer.

Comment: It is enough to find any complement $N$ of $P$, since $P\le Z$ implies $N\unlhd G$. Hence, you can also use the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem. However, the proof of the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem reduces exactly to this special situation and then needs some cohomological argument. So I agree with @spin that there is no easier solution.

Comment: @BrunoAceves It seems to me that the proof of the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem presented in the book by Kurzweil and Stellmacher "The Theory of Finite Groups: An Introduction" (Theorem 3.3.2) uses no cohomological arguments and is quite elementary.

Comment: @kabenyuk: Yes, but I think that argument is still basically doing transfer. And the transfer homomorphism can be defined in terms of group homology. I would still say that there is no proof of this result or of Schur-Zassenhaus without transfer or (co)homology.

Comment: @kabenyuk Kurzweil-Stellmacher's proof (which goes back to Gaschütz) is essentially cohomology "by hand"; therefore still not straight-forward. So again, I agree with spin (btw, I'm not BrunoAceves).

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki, I just wanted to draw Bruno's attention to a variant of the proof formulated in the question, which is quite elementary and can be presented in a first course in group theory.